# JsonLocalisation - linked translation files in TFS

Tags: json, tfs, localization, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and TFS for source control. My solution contains json files with the translations for my app made with the mvvmcross framework. The mvvmcross JsonLocalisation plugin [recommends to link the translation files](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkxHtbJ_Tlk#t=755) from a commen location to the different projects needing them.

When trying to shelve or check-in these changes, TFS complains about the translation files not being available in the platform projects.... Do any of you guys have a nice solution to that (one that doesn't include branching)?

I'd really like to avoid branching because I then need to merge the files to all my platform projects on every change I make.

How do you solve that using TFS?

Comment: is this just not a matter of workspace mapping? can you add detail of how your local and TFS build workspaces are set up for these projects?

Comment: Unfortunatly workspaces are not the solution in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am now certain branch/merge is the best option in TFS. File linking is NOT supported by TFS. I ended up putting my json translation in a resource folder outside the platform specific projects (Droid, Windows Phone and WPF). Then I branched that directory to mentioned projects.

The process for changes are now as follows. Changes made to translation files in i.e. Droid projects must be;

- Checked-in in Droid project
- Merged from Droid to CommonResource
- Checked-in in CommonResource
- Merged from CommonResource to WindowsPhone and WPF
- Checked*in in Phone & WPF

It makes it a bit more cumbersome compared to File-linking but it'll work...

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You should package your files for distribution as a NuGet package.

If you create a nuget package you can automate the update and control of the files while making them an external dependency. You then publish your nuget package to a repository (UNC or ProGet) and reference from VS.

If you edit the files you create a new versions package and deploy then update the solutions. You can automate this by having a CI build that created your nuget from the files automatically and publishing.

Look at how the Node, Angular, and other JavaScript nuget packages are composed.

Comment: I appreciate the idea using NUGET. But the reason I tried to stay away from branching/merging was to keep it fast and simple. In my opinion NUGET add just another layer of complexity in this situation.